# TSQL convert list of IP addresses to CIDR notation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given a table with the following IP Addresses

```
IPAddress
-----------
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
192.168.1.6
192.168.1.7
192.168.1.8
```

I'm looking for the following output

```
Output
---------------
192.168.1.0/29
192.168.1.8/32
```

The closest I've come was with this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(IPAddress, 1, LEN(IPAddress) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(IPAddress))), COUNT(*) 
FROM IP 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(IPAddress, 1, LEN(IPAddress) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(IPAddress)))
```

But that only gets me the subnet and # of address. Not sure how to take the next step.

Comment: The closest I've come was with this

SELECT
    SUBSTRING(IPAddress, 1, LEN(IPAddress) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(IPAddress))),
    COUNT(*)
FROM IP
GROUP BY
    SUBSTRING(IPAddress, 1, LEN(IPAddress) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(IPAddress)))

Comment: But that only gets me the subnet and # of address.  Not sure how to take the next step

Comment: Can you explain what you want in the output in plain English? It's not immediately apparent, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the subnet-mask in order to know the correct amount of host bits for your notation.

This will give you CIDR:

```
DECLARE  @IPADDRESS VARCHAR(15) = '192.168.1.1'
        ,@NETMASK VARCHAR(15) = '255.255.255.0'
        ,@NETWORKBITS VARCHAR(3)

SET @NETWORKBITS =
    CASE
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.0.0.0' THEN '8'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.128.0.0' THEN '9'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.192.0.0' THEN '10'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.224.0.0' THEN '11'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.240.0.0' THEN '12'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.248.0.0' THEN '13'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.252.0.0' THEN '14'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.254.0.0' THEN '15'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.255.0.0' THEN '16'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.255.128.0' THEN '17'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.255.192.0' THEN '18'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.255.224.0' THEN '19'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.255.240.0' THEN '20'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.255.248.0' THEN '21'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.255.252.0' THEN '22'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.255.254.0' THEN '23'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.255.255.0' THEN '24'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.255.255.128' THEN '25'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.255.255.192' THEN '26'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.255.255.224' THEN '27'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.255.255.240' THEN '28'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.255.255.248' THEN '29'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.255.255.252' THEN '30'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.255.255.254' THEN '31'
        WHEN @NETMASK = '255.255.255.255' THEN '32'
    END
PRINT @IPADDRESS + '/' @NETWORKBITS
```

Comment: @bitvector please advise whether you have the subnet masks or not and if you'd like a function, so I can give you a better answer. If you do not have the subnet masks this is not possible.

Comment: Hi Tizechie,  The only data I have is the IP Address.  I appreciate the function for the net mask, but there doesn't seem to be a good way to accomplish my goal.

Comment: @bitvector, In your question when you say you want the output 192.168.1.0/29 that is just short hand for 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.248. Maybe you aren't asking the right question? I'd be glad to assist you with your problem but you need to modify your question.